# make a shell script with fewer lines

Tags: bash, shell

I always disbale all the IOSTAT in my android's memory IOBLOCKS and just
wanted to make this code into a fewer lines

Is it possible:

```
#!/system/bin/sh

echo 0 > /sys/block/sda/queue/iostats
echo 0 > /sys/block/sdb/queue/iostats
echo 0 > /sys/block/sdc/queue/iostats
echo 0 > /sys/block/sde/queue/iostats
echo 0 > /sys/block/sdf/queue/iostats
echo 0 > /sys/block/sdd/queue/iostats
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#! /system/bin/sh -
echo 0 | tee /sys/block/sd[a-f]/queue/iostats
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner, chopped to few lines so it's easier to read:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
for z in a b c d e f;do
  echo 0 > /sys/block/sd${z}/queue/iostats
done
```

This solution uses only `echo`, and no other apps like `tee`, `awk`, `grep`...

via Bash it can be even shorter with: `{a..f}`, but I see you want/need to use `sh`